Segmentation fault when debugging assembly code compiled with Cygwin
Windows 11 64 bit, 64 bit Intel CPU
When debugging an assembly code compiled with Cygwin64 I am getting a segmentation fault..
This is my code:
.text
.global main
main:

This is how I compile it:
gcc -g -o test .\test.s

This is how I debug it:
gdb .\test.exe

In the GDB, when I enter run I get:
    (gdb) run
Starting program: /cygdrive/d/Code/asembly/.\test.exe
[New Thread 26616.0x889c]
[New Thread 26616.0x1628]
[New Thread 26616.0x3404]

Thread 1 "test" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
(gdb)


Maybe you need a ret to return from main?
